# SQL Grouping by those that has results but keeping those without

Tags: mysql

I have a big SQL query that selects totals by month and groups by merchants. It works well and displays everything I need. The problem is I also need the merchant with no transaction to show in the list. So fare, the merchant gets a total only if he did at least one transaction. We need to calculate the monthly fees even if a merchant made 0 transaction.

My current SQL looks like this.

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    m.name AS merchant_name,

DATE_FORMAT(t.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') AS DATE,
SUM(t.amount) AS total_sales,
COUNT(t.id) AS total_transactions
FROM
    merchants m
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON
    t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE
    t.transaction_date LIKE '2020-08%'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(t.transaction_date, '%Y-%m'), 
    t.merchant_id
ORDER BY
    t.transaction_date
DESC
```

So I was thinking about this ... and thought maybe I could do a second query for merchants with out transactions and merge both results together... but so fare I got no luck at all. My query returns no error but says no results. If there's a way of doing this in only one query it would be a lot better thought. Here's my second query in case.

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.name AS merchant_name,
    COUNT(t.id) as transaction_count,
    SUM(0) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(t.id) AS total_transactions,
FROM
    merchants m
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON
    t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE
    t.transaction_date like '2020-08%'
HAVING transaction_count = 0
```

My transaction table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `routing_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fund_amt` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_batch_reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_mid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chain` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_amt` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surchg_amount` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `convnce_amt` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `charge_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_plan` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chk_num` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `settlement_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorization_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargback_control_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `roc_text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trn_aci` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_scheme_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trn_ref_num` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `settlement_method` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cb_acq_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chgbk_rsn_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chgbk_rsn_desc` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mer_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `purch` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_cod` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trn_arn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `term` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ent_num` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `charge_type_description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_plus_visa` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_visa` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_Vdebit` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_Vdebit` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_mc` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_mc` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_amex` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_amex` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_discover` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_discover` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_union` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_union` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `i_plus_MCdebit` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_MCdebit` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_debit` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `pi_flash` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `converge_res` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

// 5 Transactions
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `transaction_type`, `account_number`, `routing_number`, `fund_amt`, `batch_reference`, `batch_type`, `customer_batch_reference`, `customer_name`, `merchant_name`, `external_mid`, `store_number`, `chain`, `batch_amt`, `amount`, `surchg_amount`, `convnce_amt`, `card_type`, `charge_type`, `card_plan`, `card_no`, `chk_num`, `transaction_date`, `settlement_date`, `authorization_code`, `chargback_control_no`, `roc_text`, `trn_aci`, `card_scheme_ref`, `trn_ref_num`, `settlement_method`, `currency_code`, `cb_acq_ref`, `chgbk_rsn_code`, `chgbk_rsn_desc`, `mer_ref`, `purch`, `cust_cod`, `trn_arn`, `term`, `ent_num`, `charge_type_description`, `payment_reference`, `payment_date`, `i_plus_visa`, `pi_visa`, `i_plus_Vdebit`, `pi_Vdebit`, `i_plus_mc`, `pi_mc`, `i_plus_amex`, `pi_amex`, `i_plus_discover`, `pi_discover`, `i_plus_union`, `pi_union`, `i_plus_MCdebit`, `pi_MCdebit`, `pi_debit`, `pi_flash`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `customer_id`, `merchant_id`, `batch_id`, `converge_res`) VALUES
(1, '1', '***123', '00000124162', '370.90', '17290458149', 'D', '00000000043', 'name 1', NULL, '8033407712', '', '00000', '370.90', '65.00', '0.00', '0.00', '032', '02465', 'M/C', '556923******2454', '', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '613342', NULL, '', '', 'MCFPHH5FS', '17290458152', 'ACH', 'CAD', NULL, '', '', '00065069751', NULL, '', '55259569290172904581529', NULL, '48627', 'MC CHIP DOM COMMERCIAL', '929000000127220', '2019-08-17 00:00:00', '0.03', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '2020-09-21 01:58:00', '2020-09-23 00:36:54', NULL, 1, 1, NULL),
(2, '1', '***123', '00000124162', '370.90', '17290458149', 'D', '00000000043', 'name 1', NULL, '8033407712', '', '00000', '370.90', '114.00', '0.00', '0.00', '049', '01810', 'INTC', '472409******9229', '', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '224694', NULL, '', '', '', '17290458155', 'ACH', 'CAD', NULL, '', '', '00065069754', NULL, '', '0000000000017290458155X', NULL, '48627', 'PIN DEBIT RETAIL BASE', '929000000127220', '2019-10-17 00:00:00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.09', '0.00', '2020-09-21 01:58:00', '2020-09-23 00:31:58', NULL, 1, 1, NULL),
(3, '1', '***124', '00000124162', '323.35', '73290783323', 'D', '00000000033', 'name 2', NULL, '8033407712', '', '00000', '323.35', '103.50', '0.00', '0.00', '032', '02465', 'M/C', '556960******7782', '', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '066015', NULL, '', '', 'MCFPFPTVH', '73290783327', 'ACH', 'CAD', NULL, '', '', '00064918465', NULL, '', '55259569290732907833274', NULL, '48627', 'MC CHIP DOM COMMERCIAL', '929000000127221', '2019-08-17 00:00:00', '0.05', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '2020-09-21 01:58:00', '2020-09-23 00:36:54', NULL, 2, 2, NULL),
(4, '1', '***124', '00000124162', '323.35', '73290783323', 'D', '00000000033', 'name 2', NULL, '8033407712', '', '00000', '323.35', '88.55', '0.00', '0.00', '026', '02465', 'M/C', '558700******1934', '', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '034367', NULL, '', '', 'MCBQL61VH', '73290783328', 'ACH', 'CAD', NULL, '', '', '00064918466', NULL, '', '55259569290732907833282', NULL, '48627', 'MC CHIP DOM COMMERCIAL', '929000000127221', '2019-08-17 00:00:00', '0.04', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '2020-09-21 01:58:00', '2020-09-23 00:36:54', NULL, 2, 2, NULL),
(5, '1', '***125', '00000124162', '323.35', '73290783323', 'D', '00000000033', 'name 3', NULL, '8033407712', '', '00000', '323.35', '71.30', '0.00', '0.00', '026', '02465', 'M/C', '552822******0618', '', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '2019-10-16 00:00:00', '006983', NULL, '', '', 'MCO00Q4RH', '73290783324', 'ACH', 'CAD', NULL, '', '', '00064918462', NULL, '', '55259569290732907833241', NULL, '48627', 'MC CHIP DOM COMMERCIAL', '929000000127221', '2019-08-17 00:00:00', '0.04', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '2020-09-21 01:58:00', '2020-09-23 00:36:54', NULL, 3, 2, NULL);
```

In the above we have 5 transaction owned by 3 merchants. Let say I have 5 merchants. How can I end up with 5 results where 2 have empty totals

Comment: Reduce your query just to the problem you facing. We need [mcve]. With the emphasis on ***minimal***.

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect that you could explain this problem with a simpler example

Comment: Please do not downvote ... If I am missing something just ask for it ;-) Thanks for the help! I made the query smaller and also provided the transaction table + 5 transactions. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition from the WHERE-clause into the LEFT JOIN so that the condition will not exclude the merchants with no transactions. The `t.id` in SELECT in your first query does not really make sense, maybe you meant `m.id`?

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.name AS merchant_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(t.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') AS DATE,
    ifnull(SUM(t.amount),0) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(t.id) AS total_transactions
FROM
    merchants m
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON
    t.merchant_id = m.id and t.transaction_date LIKE '2020-08%'
GROUP BY
    m.id,
    m.name,
    DATE_FORMAT(t.transaction_date, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Thanks this makes ton of sense! I will give this a try later tonight!